# Laravel DB::raw prevent SQL Injection without setBindings

Tags: laravel, sql-injection

I have a dynamic query for filtering, and now I have a problem where I need to use DB::raw for ordering by

```
$this->query->orderBy(\DB::raw("POSITION(\"$value\" IN $column)", 'asc'))
```

But now here I have a SQL Injection protection issue, how can I prevent `$value` and `$column` from SQL Injection without using `->setBindings`

I cant use `->setBindings` 'cause I have dinamic numbers of filter columns depending on the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statements can't evaluate column names, so you need to use whitelisting to protect against injections into `$column`.

To protect against value, you can either force it to be an integer or float type, or use orderByRaw which accepts an array of parameters:

```
$this->query->orderByRaw("POSITION(? IN $column)", [$value])
```

Comment: actually I don't need protection to `$column` cause it's from an array that I create, it works perfectly, thank you

Comment: You might want to put `$column` in back-ticks just in case it matches a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`orderByRaw`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw) which will accept an array of bindings.

```
$this->query->orderByRaw('POSITION(? IN ?) asc', [$value, $column]);
```

Comment: You can't use parameters for column names.

Comment: This solution won't return an error, but it'll treat the second parameter as a literal string, not the name of a column. So it won't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below,

```
$orderByQuery = "select * from table order by POSITION(:value IN :column) asc";
$this->query->select($orderByQuery, [
    "value" => $value,
    "column" => $column
])
```